# How can I use "member" variables of a module inside a function?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Modules::TextStuff;  

use strict;  
use warnings;  
use Exporter;  
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);  
our @EXPORT = qw(get_text);  

my $author;  

my $text_tmp1 =<<'ENG';  
This is a template text  
by $author.   
ENG


sub get_text {  
        my $tmp = shift @_;  
        $author = shift @_;  
        print "In sub author= $author lang = $tmp \n";  
        my $final_str = eval('$text_'.$tmp);  
        print "$final_str \n";  
        return $final_str;  
}  
1;
```

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;  
use warnings;  

use Modules::TextStuff;  

my $str = get_text('tmp1','jim');  
print $str;
```

When I run the test script it does not work. I get:

> In sub author=jim lang = eng
>
> Variable "$text_tmp1" is not available at (eval 1) line 2. Use of
>   uninitialized value $final_str in concatenation (.) or string

How can I fix this?

Comment: Whenever you're using some weird method to dynamically create a named variable you should be thinking of using a hash instead.

Comment: -1. There's no way that code gives that output, even after fixing the compilation errors.

Comment: @ikegami:I have no idea what you mean.If you copy-paste the code you should get the same error/warnings I mention.I am using Perl 5-14 Cygwin in case it matters

Comment: Despite your edit, it still doesn't compile or give the error once you fix the compilation error. But I figured out what you changed. Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami:What do you mean it doesn't compile.After your comment, I copy/pasted the code and run it.The only problem I had was a wrong name of a variable (my bad there). Other than that, this is the error I get

Comment: @Jim, It would give `Can't find string terminator "ENG" anywhere before EOF`, which I fixed. You had spaces after `ENG`. You yourself admitted getting this error already!

Answer (score 1):

Combining strings to create variables names is usually a bad idea. You could salvage your current program using `our $text_tmp1 = ...` instead of `my $text_tmp1 = ...`, but I think you should consider a different approach, like a hash:

```
my %templates = (

    tmp1 => <<ENG,
This is a template text
by \$author.
ENG

    tmp2 => <<ESP,
Esta es templata texta de \$author.
ESP
);

sub get_text {
    ...
    my $final_str = eval( $templates{$tmp} );
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you want to interpolate a string into a template, usually `sprintf` would be the choice, not `eval`.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of the variable out of scope?

Comment: Additionally this does not work. It gives: `Can't find string terminator "ENG" anywhere before EOF`

Comment: @hobbs:What do you mean.I copied exactly like this

Answer (score 1):

The error you asked about is generated when `eval EXPR` tries to grab the value of a variable that did exist, but no longer exists.

```
>perl -wE"{ my $x = 123; sub f { eval '$x' } } say '<'.f().'>';"
Variable "$x" is not available at (eval 1) line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
<>
```

Remember, executing a file (such as a script or a module) is done in its own a lexical scope, just like the one the curlies create above.

---

It can be fixed by keeping the variable alive by not letting it go out of scope

```
>perl -wE"my $x = 123; sub f { eval '$x' } say '<'.f().'>';"
<123>
```

But that's not an option for you.

Other options include making the variable a global variable.

```
>perl -wE"{ our $x = 123; sub f { eval '$x' } } say '<'.f().'>';"
<123>
```

Or forcing the sub to capture it so it doesn't cease to exist.

```
>perl -wE"{ my $x = 123; sub f { $x if 0; eval '$x' } } say '<'.f().'>';"
<123>
```

(The `if 0` silences the "void context" warning.)

---

That said, it looks like you're trying to re-invent the [wheel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template). Don't invent another half-assed templating system.

Comment: I don't understand how is example 1 different than 2 or how I can use them in my case

Comment: In the first snippet, `$x` no longer exists by the time `f()` is called. In the second snippet, `$x` still exists. Look that the curlies.

Comment: In a nutshell: What I need is a way to interpolate to a string a variable which is "encapsulated" in the module.

Comment: @Jim, That's called a template. I linked you to a proper templating system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at several things:

- First of all, `$text_tmp1` is not a package variable. It's lexically scoped since you declared it with `my`. If you need it as a package variable and for it to be visible in all or your subroutines, you need to declare it with `our`.
- Your module doesn't *compile* as written. You are trying to source in `$author`, but it's not defined.
- What are you doing with `eval`? This is wrong on so many levels.

Here's how I would do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

package Modules::TextStuff;  

use strict;  
use warnings;  
use Exporter qw(import);
use Carp;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(get_text);

our %templates;                # This is now a package variable

#
# TEMPLATES
#

$templates{tmp1}=<<TEMPLATE;   # We'll use `%s` for replacements
This is a template text  
by %s.
TEMPLATE

$templates{tmp2}=<<TEMPLATE;
This is another template and we will substitute 
in %s in this one too.
TEMPLATE

sub get_text {  
    my $template = shift;  
    my $author   = shift;
    if ( not exists $templates{$template} ) {
        croak qq(Invalid template name "$template");
    }
    return sprintf $templates{$template}, $author;
}
1;
```

I'll make each of these templates an entry in my `%templates` hash. No need for `eval` to calculate out a variable name for the template. Also notice that I can now actually test whether the user passed in a valid template or not with the [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html).

Also note that `%template` is declared with `our` and not `my`. This makes it available in the entire package including any subroutines in my package.

I also use `@EXPORT_OK` instead of `@EXPORT`. It's considered more polite. You're requesting permission to pollute the user's namespace. It's like knocking on someone's door and asking if you can have a beer rather than barging in and rummaging through their fridge for a beer.

Note how I use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to handle the replaceable parameters. This again removes the need for eval.

I also prefer to use `#! /usr/bin/env perl` on my program header since it's more compatible with things like [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl). You're using `/usr/bin/env` to find the executable Perl program that's in the user's path. This way, you don't have to know whether it's `/bin/perl`, `/usr/bin/perl`, `/usr/local/bin/perl`, or `$HOME/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.0/bin/perl`

To use your module, I would do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use Modules::TextStuff qw(get_text);

say get_text('tmp1','jim');
```

Pretty much the same call you made. This prints out:

```
This is a template text  
by jim.
```